# Overlay in Sony Smart TV Application

Tags: android, sony

I am trying to develop a Smart TV application for the Sony Smart TV and am wondering if your platform allows overlay over live TV. Our application displays chat messages received over live TV or whatever is plugged into in an HDMI port and I  am wondering if that is possible on your platform. I do not intend on manipulating the TV broadcast, I simply place transparent HTML over it. The following links are examples of our intended application:

http://gibrscreenshots.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/screenshots/screenshot1.jpg
http://gibrscreenshots.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/screenshots/screenshot2.jpg

Is something similar to the above screenshots possible on the platform?